# Post-build Actions part does not see injected environment variable

Tags: jenkins, properties, environment-variables, properties-file, post-build

A script generates a `properties` file to work-space in an `Execute shell` block in the `Build` section. This file is available at work-space after script execution and in case of `Failed` build (`Conditional steps (multiple)` block in the `Build` section) this properties file will be injected. My Jenkins job sends an E-mail (`Editable Email Notification` block) in case if `Failed` build and it should contains the variable from properties file but it doesn't see this variable. FYI: This block can use other environment variables.
I have cross-checked the properties file and it contains the required variable in every case.

**Properties file in work-space:**

[image]

**Environment variable injection from properties file:**

This `Steps to to run if condition is met` block contains more other actions and these work fine. It means the running can reach this block.

[image]

**Editable Email Notification block in Post-build:**

[image]

**If I check the `Environment Variables` option in a build, I can see the variable:**

[image]

**But when I get the mail, it doesn't contain the variable:**

[image]

Any idea how can I solve it or what should I change?

**NOTE:** The variable is unique and not really related to `Gerrit` so I cannot use another variable which comes form `Gerrit`. Just the name of var is a little tricky.

Comment: Try use ${env.GERRIT_CHANGE_LINK}

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem was that the job was not able to reach the `Conditional steps (multiple)` block in case of `Failed` status. I have found a solution and I have answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer for my question. The `Jenkins` or the plugin has limitation. It cannot handle the Failure state. If the previous `execute shell` block is failed then the running won't reach the `Conditional steps (multiple)` block.

On the other hand, I have found a "workaround" for this problem.

**1. step**

You need to exit from the `Execute shell` block with a specific return code. Eg.: 111

**2. step**

You need to set the `Exit code to set build unstable` filed to your specific exit code. (You can find this field in advanced option of `Execute shell` block.) As you can see in the below picture.

[image]

**3. step**

Set the `Conditional steps (multiple)` block to handle the `Unstable` state. With this solution the running is able to run into `Conditional steps (multiple)` block.

[image]

**4. step**

Create an `Execute shell` block inside the `Conditional steps (multiple)` block **after you prepare everything what you want in case of job failed**. It means after this block your job status changes to `Failed` from `Unstable`.

[image]

Whit this solution you can handle the failed job and in the end you will get a real failed job (not unstable).

Not the most elegant solution but it works.